# Symfony2 problems with cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I have worked with one project on Symfony2. It works on my local server, but when I uploaded this project to the hosting, it has stopped working. Over time I have found, that problem is with the cache directory.

So uploading the cache from the local server to the hosting has solved this problem.

What can the problem be? What are the main problems with cache on Symfony2?

Comment: have you cleared the cache using the app/console cache:clear command? This should solve your cache problems

Comment: of course, I have cleared cache. I haven't habit to upload the cache to production. So, first there was no cache on hosting and all what I had as result - was error 500. This error disappeared after cache uploading. Also I noticed, that only one variant of cache solve the problem (i have backup it).
When I gone to admin panel of project and then upload cache - project not worked on hosting. If I no use admin panel on local and uploading cache to hosting, all except admin-panel worked fine.

Comment: is it possible that cache formed depend on server configuration?

Comment: What does the prod error log says about your 500? It strongly suggests write issues.

Comment: nothing says. empty log

Comment: Is the log directory writable? What does your server error log say?

Comment: I noticed, somebody search for my questions and answers and downvote it without any reason. I have any idea, how to prevent this.

Comment: @k0pernikus looks like you are right (problems with write issues)

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Random downvotes do happen, don't let that dispirit you. It's nice yet not mandatory to explain to reason of a downvote. I suggest reading the faq on [how to ask a good question here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and work from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't upload the cache folder. These are only temporary files. Look at the [docs about how to deploy](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html).

Most likely you have to run:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

Also check that the cache and log folder is writable as pointed out on the [installation documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html):

Comment: first I have uploaded project without cache and it no worked, despite that rights for the folder was 777. Please, see my detailed explanation at comments below my question.